# Using R code to simulate data iteratively in Proc IML and then analyze in SAS procedure, a faster way?

Tags: r, sas, simulation, do-loops, sas-iml

The following codes are what I thought of, it is kind of slow, any suggestions? Thank you!

The details are that first create a dataset in `proc iml` using R code, then transport that into regular SAS `proc mixed` statement to analyze it, then use `proc append` to store the results, then iterate the process 10000 times.

```
proc iml;
  do i= 1 to 100000;  
    submit / R;
       library(mvtnorm)
       library(dplyr)
       library(tidyr)
       beta <- matrix(1:50, byrow = TRUE,10,5)
       sigma <- matrix(1:25, 5)
       sigma [lower.tri(sigma )] = t(sigma )[lower.tri(sigma )]
       sample <- t(apply(beta, 1, function(m) rmvnorm(1, mean=m, sigma=sigma)))
       Group = rep(factor(LETTERS[1:2]),each=5,1)
       sample <- cbind(sample,Group,c(1:5))
       concat <- function(x) paste0('Visit', x[, 2], 'Time', x[, 1])
       cnames <- c(paste0("Time", 1:5),"Group","ID")
       colnames(sample) <- cnames
       sample <- data.frame(sample)
       sample <- gather(sample, Visit, Response, paste0("Time", 1:5), factor_key=TRUE)
    endsubmit;

    call ImportDataSetFromR( "rdata", "sample" );

    submit;
       Proc mixed data=rdata;
          ods select none;
          class Group Visit ID;
          model Response = Visit|Group;
          repeated  Visit/ subject=ID type=un;
          ods output  Tests3=Test;
       run;
       proc append data=Test base=result force ;
       run;
    ENDSUBMIT;
  end;
Quit;
proc print data=result;
run;
```

Comment: @Parfait Thanks, please see above.

Comment: `gather()` is not a base R function and you do not include its `library`. BTW - with 10,000 iterations, how fast did you expect processing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ideal approach would be to do the full simulation in SAS/IML because that would minimize the transfer of data between SAS and R. You can [use the RANDNORMAL function to simulate multivariate normal data](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/04/10/generate-multiple-mvn-samples.html). Use the CREATE/APPEND statements to save the simulated samples to a SAS data set. Then call PROC MIXED and use a BY statement to analyze all the samples. See ["Simulation in SAS,"](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2012/07/18/simulation-in-sas-the-slow-way-or-the-by-way.html) for the general ideas. No SUBMIT blocks are required. If you experience programming issues, consult the "Simulation" posts on [*The DO Loop* blog](https://blogs.sas.com/content/tag/simulation/), or if you intend to do a lot of simulation in SAS, you might want to find a copy of [*Simulating Data with SAS* (Wicklin, 2013)](https://support.sas.com/en/books/authors/rick-wicklin.html)

If you don't know SAS/IML well enough to run the simulation, then generate all 100,000 samples in R (vectorize, if possible) and manufacture a SampleID variable to identify each sample. Then import the entire data into SAS and use the BY statement trick to do the analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know exactly what you are doing so this has to be general.

Move the loop inside of the R code.  Stay inside R to generate 1 big data frame and then import that into SAS.  Looping over those submits will be slower.  There is necessary overhead to call R, import the data from R (which is another R call), and then to run your SAS append.  Putting the loop into R eliminates that overhead.

Comment: I have added my R coded above, could you tell me how to generate multiple date frames and store them into 1 big data frame? Sorry I am new to R. And the new 1 big date frame needs to have a column of index showing which iteration it comes from, right?